# REST move+document with semicolon issue

Tags: web-services

I am trying to use a Web Request in Sharepoint 2016 to move files from once folder to another using the following request:

Note the %3B in the filename. (%3B = Semicolon). It returns **Unexpected error occurred while making the request.**

I have tried the ; directly with no luck as well.  Is there another way to escape or encode the semicolon to make it work?

Thank-you!

**URL:** http://mywebsite/mysharepointsite/_vti_bin/_vti_aut/author.dll

**POST**

**Headers:**

***Name*:** X-Vermeer-Content-Type

***Value*:** application/x-www-form-urlencoded

**Content:**

method=move+document:14.0.2.5420&service_name=/&oldUrl=Published Documents/test%3Bdoc%2Epdf&newUrl=Published Documents/2016/test%3Bdoc%2Epdf&url_list=[]&rename_option=findbacklinks&put_option=overwrite,migrationsemantics

Comment: This is a Sharepoint API question.  I mentioned NINTEX to give people reference that I am not looking for a coded solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you use '\' for escape character in REST API because special characters are not used in rest API so we need to escape this characters.

Comment: That works brilliantly.  I never would have expected that \%3B would work, but it does.

Comment: Yes, In REST API for escape character we need to use '\'  for all special character.